# Complex CSS Animation Repeating - use Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a CSS animation which is quite complex, ie. it's layered, or brings in two images, one a background image, then an `<img>` tag inside that, to overlay the original.

Demo is here: http://wdb.blazeoven.co.uk/

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
<a href="services.php">
  <div class="col-sm-3 home-circle" id="one">
      <img class="bottom" id="five" src="/assets/img/prop-consultants.png" alt="residential block in grounds">
  </div>
</a>
<a href="services.php">
  <div class="col-sm-3 home-circle" id="two">
    <img class="bottom" id="six" src="/assets/img/chartered-surveyors.png" alt="old residential house doorways">
  </div>
</a>
<a href="services.php">
  <div class="col-sm-3 home-circle" id="three">
    <img class="bottom" id="seven" src="/assets/img/managing-agents.png" 
      alt="row of shops">
  </div>
</a>
<a href="services.php">
  <div class="col-sm-3 home-circle" id="four">
    <img class="bottom" id="eight" src="/assets/img/city-central.png" alt="City shop premises">
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; } }
@keyframes fadeOut { from { opacity:1; } to { opacity:0; } }
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.home-banner .container a .col-sm-3 {
   opacity:0; 
   -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1; 
   -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
   animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

   -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
   -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
   animation-fill-mode:forwards;

   -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
   -moz-animation-duration:1s;
   animation-duration:1s;
  }

.home-banner #one {
  background:url('/assets/img/propcons.svg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;

  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.home-banner #two {
  background:url('/assets/img/charsurv.svg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;

  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.home-banner #three {
  background:url('/assets/img/manage.svg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;

  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.4s;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
.home-banner #four {
  background:url('/assets/img/citycen.svg') center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;

  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.8s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.8s;
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
}
.grey-banner img.bottom {
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-animation:fadeOut ease-in 1; 
 -moz-animation:fadeOut ease-in 1;
 animation:fadeOut ease-in 1;

 // -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
 // -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
 // animation-direction: alternate;


 -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; 
 -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
 animation-fill-mode:forwards;

 -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
 -moz-animation-duration:1s;
 animation-duration:1s;
}
.grey-banner img#five {
-webkit-animation-delay: 6.8s;
-moz-animation-delay: 6.8s;
animation-delay: 6.8s;
}

.grey-banner img#six {
-webkit-animation-delay: 7.4s;
-moz-animation-delay: 7.4s;
animation-delay: 7.4s;
}

.grey-banner img#seven {
-webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
-moz-animation-delay: 8s;
animation-delay: 8s;
}
.grey-banner img#eight {
-webkit-animation-delay: 8.6s;
-moz-animation-delay: 8.6s;
animation-delay: 8.6s;
}
```

Trouble is, the client is requesting that it repeats again. That is, it plays in reverse, then starts again.

I have tried unsuccessfully to do this with CSS, is there a succinct way to do it with Javascript?

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the animation using `animation-iteration-count`:

```css
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 3; /* Firefox 5 -> 15 */
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-iteration-count: 3; /* Firefox 16, IE 10 */
```

Not supported in IE 9 and earlier.

You can also use the value `infinite` to repeat over and over.

### Edit:

As I commented you can try with cubic-bezier:
Use no delay, and animation-duration:10s. You can try with these cubic-bezier values on the animation-timing-function for the four images:

```
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5);
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4,-0.7, 0.4, 1.8);
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,-1.7, 0.7, 1.8);
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.9,-1.6, 0.8, 0.8);
```

I have not tried this myself, and I am not sure how well it works with the values that are < 0 and > 1 (which is not standard).

If you want to play around with how the cubic-bezier is set up, you can use the tool at http://cubic-bezier.com to help finding useful values.

Comment: Hi Awe, thanks for your answer. This did help immensely, although it's looking a little eclectic ... I don't think this is possible but there's no way of stipulating a delay between iterations that you know of?

Comment: Instead of using `fadein` as the `animation-timing-function`, you could try to make a custom animation speed with `cubic-bezier`. See http://cubic-bezier.com to play around with possible values to get a grip on what it means. I don't know if this will help you, but it's worth a try. You can even use negative values, but I don't know what effect that will have on your case.

Comment: Using different speeds on the cubic-bezier might be an option in combination with longer animation span, and no delay (use the bezier to act as the delay effect) this way the iteration count will match the entire animation, and not just loop on the 1s span.

Comment: Hm thanks Awe, will give that a go now and let you know :-)

Answer (score 1):

You said the your client just wanted the animation to play normally, then play in reverse and then repeat.

It so happens that there is a CSS property called `animation-direction`. This property states whether the animation plays normally or in reverse. Use `animation-direction: alternate;` to – as the property value indicates – alternate between playing normally and in reverse.

Read more here: [MDN: animation-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Phililip, yours and @awe's comments have helped a lot, I am approaching a solution although ... it looks a little eclectic at the minute.